# Java - Parsing a Date from a String

Tags: java, date, parsing

I want to parse a `java.util.Date` from a String. I tried the following code but got unexpected output:

```
Date getDate() {
    Date date = null;

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
    try {
        date = sdf.parse("Sat May 11");
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(URLExtractor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }

    return date;
}
```

When I run the above code, I got the following output:

```
Mon May 11 00:00:00 IST 1970
```

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: Because what output did you expect/want?

Comment: I was expecting "Sat" instead of "Mon".

Comment: Then you have to specify the year, you can't get a Saturday if that date is a Monday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not specified a year in your string. The default year is 1970. And in 1970 the 11th of May was a Monday - `SimpleDateFormat` is simply ignoring the weekday in your string.

From the [javadoc of DateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html):

> The date is represented as a `Date` object or
>    as the milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

Answer (score 0):

if the year is the problem you can add `y` for year:

```
 public Date getDate() {
    Date date = null;

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd y");
    try {
        date = sdf.parse("May 11 2010");
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(URLExtractor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }

    return date;
}
 System.out.println(getDate());
```

`Tue May 11 00:00:00 EDT 2010`

**Edit:**

To get the correct day of the week you need to specify the date (with the year). I edited the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a year within the Format to get the correct output.

If you don't specify any year, the default is 1970.